# Why does the Visual Studio Debugger stop working during debugging ASP.NET project saying ~"Jump not possible"

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

Sometimes when I am debugging my ASP.NET(c#) and javascript code in Visual Studio 2017, the debugger stops stepping through the code saying

> > ~ Jumping not possible. The operation could not be completed. It should be repeated.

The original german translation is:

> > Springen nicht möglich. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Er sollte wiederholt werden."

It seems like the debugger is no longer attached to the process, or some process in the Background stops working.

Does someone consider the same Problem and knows how to fix this behaviour?

I am using Visual Studio 2017, ASP.NET (C#) pages with HTML5/jquery/Ajax calls.

The positions in code where the Debugger stops, seem to be random. It is extremely annoying because all I can do is to stop and restart debugging, and I have to click again all the way through my testing scenario.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? If JohnB's answer solved your problem, please consider checking is as the "accepted answer" to your question. ;)

Comment: Since the problem happened mere "randomly", I had to test a few days to see if it still appears. But you're right, I should have given any feedback in between. JohnB's answer solved this indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround to the [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/349178/visual-studio-professional-2017-build-1586-debuggi.html):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

Turn off

> > Break all processes when one process breaks.

However that breaks the Edit and continue experience...

Comment: Thank you, for the quick answer and sorry for my late Feedback. I turned off this Option in the General Settings and had to try a few days since the behaviour only appeared "randomly"... It seems to have solved the problem though.